# Trying to align with autolayout

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, constraints

I have this view hierarchy on a viewController

```
view
 | |_____ redView
 |            |______orangeView
 |
 |
 |_______ blackView
```

`blackView` height is always 126 pt. `orangeView` has a `127:155` aspect ratio and is inside `redView`. The result is this seen on iPhone 3.5".

[image]

Now I would like to make this scale proportionally to all iPhone sizes. Doing it on Photoshop, I would like it to be like this:

[image]

Notice two things: `orangeView` should keep its aspect ratio and the iPhone 4 is the only one where the `organgeView` height is the same as `redView`'s. On the other phones, what is the same is the width.

Because of this, I cannot figure out what constrains I should apply to `orangeView` to make it scale like I want.

What I am obtaining is this:

[image]

The constrains I have so far for `orangeView` are these: centerX to redView, centerY to redView, aspecratio (127:155) and same height of redView, but this last is incorrect and the reason why I am having the result I have. How can I make orange view expand to reach the maximum horizontally or vertically, keeping its aspect ratio, on all devices and continue to be completely within redView area?

Comment: Can you try replacing "same height of redView" with "same width of redView"? -- Edit: ah no, that does not work for 3.5

Comment: no and the reason is, look at the first picture. On iPhone 4 the widths cannot be the same. This is the problem. On iPhone 4, the heights are the same, on other iPhones, the widths are the same.

Comment: Your math doesn't seem to add up if I understand your requirements. On a 4" iPhone you have 442 points vertical after you subtract the 126 point bottom view. If you want to maintain that aspect ratio, then the height of the orange view shouldn't be the same as the red view, it should be 390.

Comment: Like I said, on the iPhone 4 the **heights** are the same on the other iphones, the **widths** are the same. On the iPhone 5 you mention, orangeView should have 320x390. I said iPhone 4, not iphone 4"

Comment: I don't know how to do it in pure autolayout, but you could depending on the device ratio either activate the constraint for the same height or same width (or you have both and change the priorities).

Comment: @Masa - what??? how do I do that? I would have to build the orangeView in code?

Comment: You can try connecting the Constraints as an IBOutlet to your ViewController and manipulate them in viewDidLoad. (Just an idea.)

Comment: Interface Builder is whining after I added the constraints you suggested...

Comment: The same constraints as you have described for the orange view expect remove the "same height". Then add two constraints: leading space and top space with constant 0. Now watch what happens if you either reduce the priority of leading or top to high=750. They cannot be the same. If you reduce leading to high it works for 3.5". If you reduce top to high it works for the others. If that works for you, you have to find a way to manipulate them in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do what you want by setting the width and height of the orange view equal to the red view, but with low priority (I used 250). Also you need one that says the orange view is <= the width of the red view with a priority of 1000 (otherwise the orange view extends past the red view's bounds in the width direction).

[image]

So, the ones that say equal width and equal height to superview both have a priority of 250.

Comment: Man, you are a genius! I was not aware that you could have multiple constraints related to width and height! Genius!